# How to invoke visual recognition api in watson conversation service?

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I have been developing a health care assistant using IBM Watson, I want to invoke the Visual Recognition API in Watson Assistant(*formerly Conversation*) service. I've created the Visual Recognition service credentials and created custom training data set using images. **How do I invoke that into my conversation service?**

Comment: Before your question can be answered you need to determine how the Assistant service receives the image for which it is going to perform visual recognition. Is this something that the user has provided? Has it been posted into a database? Is it in the form of a url to a web resource?

Comment: So the scenario goes like, the user will use the camera feature to show their skin related problems like rashes or dandruff like that, so I'm planning to make this app to capture the image live and analyse it to suggest the remedies to cure it. Basically it captures the live camera image, analyse it with the help of trained datasets and present the remedies. I hope this clarifies. @chughts

Comment: So you capture an image, run some sort of visual recognition analysis on it, and send a summary of the analysis to the assistant service. Do you have your own orchestration layer code or are you using an Assistant tooling provided interface?

Comment: I'm just trying to mimic the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01a5bqnpNDs this video, which is a demo of Watson Visual Recognition Services for Core ML Demo, which has been done for iOS devices. I want to try it out in Android studio. I couldn't find any code that would provide me the surface to build my app. @chughts

Comment: That is a native iOS app that makes use of CoreML, I don't think that it has Watson Assistant as part of the app. Another issue is that CoreML is iOS only and I don't think that there is an equivalent for Android. You can still make use of Watson Visual Recognition, but as an API that your app / orchestration layer invokes passing in the image.